# In Ruby, how can I reference a lambda defined in a module?

Tags: ruby, module, lambda

This code used to work until I put my lambda function in a module.

Here is the lambda function:

```
module GalleryGenerator
  @add_links_to_descriptions = lambda do |mutable_viewable_content|
    mutable_viewable_content.description = add_links_to_sources(mutable_viewable_content.description)
    return mutable_viewable_content
  end
  #...
end
```

Here is how it is being used:

```
include GalleryGenerator

gallery = ViewableGallery.new(gallery_config.title, gallery_config.description, gallery_config.slug, \
gallery_config.sources, gallery_config.upload_date, gallery_config.map_url, gallery_config.map_title, \
gallery_config.year, viewable_photos).
update_using( \
    add_tabs_before_every_description_line(2), \
    @add_links_to_descriptions)
```

That's the error:

```
/home/mike/Development/Projects/FT/gallery_generator/lib/gallery_generator/viewable_gallery.rb:26:in `block in update_using': undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /home/mike/Development/Projects/FT/gallery_generator/lib/gallery_generator/viewable_gallery.rb:25:in `each'
from /home/mike/Development/Projects/FT/gallery_generator/lib/gallery_generator/viewable_gallery.rb:25:in `update_using'
from bin/gallery_generator:32:in `<main>'
```

If the lambda message is not in a module, it all works. I suspect that it's looking for @add_links_to_descriptions in the wrong place now that's in the module...

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Isn't kind of awkward to use a named anonymous function? Remember, you can always turn a method into a lambda using the 'method' method.

Comment: Jim, I'm new to Ruby and it's quite likely all of my Ruby code is awkward. :) What's the 'method' method?

Comment: In any object, you can get a method of that object by using the 'method' method. This method is of the class Method, which has functions to invoke, etc. It also has the ability to be converted into a lambda using the to_proc method.

However, often this is unnecessary because normally you pass lambdas into functions as blocks; here there is a shortcut that you can use: &:my_method_name will interpret this as a lambda for that particular function.

Comment: That's true, &:add_links_to_descriptions works. But why does it work and @add_links_to_descriptions didn't?

Comment: I can't tell you without knowing update_using, but if the & did work, then it's because each method has a special "block" argument, and this argument is reserved for a block that is passed to a method. When you use Enumerable.each, you pass in an anonymous block (called a Proc). Doing this actually provides the block that you enter as the block parameter. However, if you want, you can instead use a variable by using the &. Using the & simply tells you to use the block argument.

Comment: But why did the : (colon) help? This language is too cryptic for me, I think...

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0BNCZ0kw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
module GalleryGenerator
  def self.add_links_to_descriptions
    lambda do |mutable_viewable_content|
      mutable_viewable_content.description = add_links_to_sources(mutable_viewable_content.description)
      return mutable_viewable_content
    end
  end
  #...
end
```

and call it with `GalleryGenerator.add_links_to_descriptions`

Comment: module's shouldn't use instance methods since they're not instantiated - but at worst this is a difference of opinion...why the downvote?

Comment: I do not know where the downvote came from, second he is including the module, in that case it is better to use instance methods and not to couple itself to the `GalleryGenerator` module name and please check what instance method means.

Comment: @Mike btw `return` is superfluous, you can just leave it off!

Comment: Sorry, I can't judge the validity of these contradictory comments, I don't have the knowledge.

Comment: This allows me to pass arguments, to pass lambdas as arguments to other lambdas, so I'm going to upvote this approach. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby, variables whose name starts with an `@` sigil are *instance variables*, i.e. variables that belong to a particular *object* (or *instance*).

In this case, the instance variable `@add_links_to_descriptions` belongs to the object referenced by the constant `GalleryGenerator`, and can only be accessed by it, no other object.

The only things which are accessible by other objects in Ruby, are methods. So, you need to define a method which returns the value of the instance variable. Such a method is called an *attribute reader* in Ruby, and there is a handy method for automatically generating them, called [`Module#attr_reader`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader):

```
class << GalleryGenerator
  attr_reader :add_links_to_descriptions
end

class Foo
  GalleryGenerator.add_links_to_descriptions.(nil)
end
```

Alternatively, you could use a constant instead of an instance variable. Constants are denoted with a capital letter:

```
module GalleryGenerator
  AddLinksToDescriptions = -> mutable_viewable_content {
    mutable_viewable_content.tap do |m|
      m.description = add_links_to_sources(m.description)
    end
  }
end

class Foo
  GalleryGenerator::AddLinksToDescriptions.(nil)
end
```

Or, you cold use a class hierarchy variable (denoted by a `@@` sigil):

```
module GalleryGenerator
  @@add_links_to_descriptions = -> mutable_viewable_content {
    mutable_viewable_content.tap do |m|
      m.description = add_links_to_sources(m.description)
    end
  }
end

class Foo
  include GalleryGenerator
  @@add_links_to_descriptions.(nil)
end
```

Comment: Hi Jörg, thanks for your comprehensive answer. What about the solution suggested above, "&:my_method_name"?

Answer (score 1):

Just make the `lambda` a constant or instance method returning the lambda.

```
module GalleryGenerator
 LINKS_TO_DESCRIPTION_ADDER =  lambda do |mutable_viewable_content|
    mutable_viewable_content.description = add_links_to_sources(mutable_viewable_content.description)
    return mutable_viewable_content
  end
  #...
end

update_using( \
  add_tabs_before_every_description_line(2), \
  LINKS_TO_DESCRIPTION_ADDER)
```

Comment: And if LINKS_TO_DESCRIPTION_ADDER were to accept an argument?

Comment: That is why i wrote constant or instance method.